# Excel Macro module to copy variable columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro that copies variable columns from one sheet to another. For example I would like to copy column A-sheet 3 to column A-sheet 6, column B-sheet 3 to column C-sheet 6, etc.

I was hoping to create one procedure that can be called many times.

```
Sub Copy_Column(a, b)
    Sheets(3).Select
    Range("a11:a1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(6).Select
    Range("b15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Sub Master()
    Call Copy_Column(a, a)
End Sub
```

What happens is it copies Column A in sheet 3 to Column B in sheet 6, not in Column A.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you never use the `a` and `b` parameters in the routine.
Did you mean them to represent column letters? If so, then

```
Sub Copy_Column(byval a as string, byval b as string)
    Sheets(3).Range(a & "11:" & a & "1000").Copy Sheets(6).Range(b & "15")
End Sub

Sub Master()
    Call Copy_Column("a", "a")
End Sub
```